# 2d sprite topples over due to circle collider

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I am completely new to unity nd was trying to create a simple 2d platformer. I a trying to use a box collider and a circle collider for my Player. I am using circle collider because I have heard it helps more accurate collision detection for a player. The problem is that my player topples over when it falls to ground.
Please tell me if there is any fix for my problem.[image: This is how the colliders are placed for the character]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `RigidBody2D` component of your character, expand the `Constraints` dropdown. Here you can freeze your character's rotation around the Z-axis to prevent your character from falling.